# Filter by datatype

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I'm trying to filter by datatype in DBpedia. For example:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER ( datatype(?o) = xsd:integer) 
    } 
LIMIT 10
```

But I get no results, while there are certainly integer values. I get the same  from other endpoints using Virtuoso, but I do get results from alternative endpoints. What could be the problem? If Virtuoso does not implement this SPARQL function properly, what to use instead?

Comment: This seems unlikely to be your actual intended query, and I think you may be working on an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), resolving which may not get you much closer to ultimate success.  Often best to provide an idea of what you're really working on, so advice can be more relevant.

Comment: Yes, this is not my actual query. For my actual problem, I wanted to give a similar example with DBpedia, as my endpoint is not public. And when doing so, I discovered this problem, which I find serious and would very much like get a solution for it. (My actual problem is that a `FILTER (?year > ...)` when I have `BIND (year(?x) as ?year)` where ?x is of xsd:dateTime, gives error, but I'll ask this separately.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expensive query, since it has to traverse all triples (`?s ?p ?o .`). The query's execution time exceeds the maximum time configured for the [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) instance that serves DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint at http://dbpedia.org/sparql.

If you don't use the `timeout` parameter, then you will get a time out error (`Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out`). When you use the `timeout` (by default set to `30000` for the DBpedia endpoint), you will get incomplete results that will contain HTTP headers like these:

```
X-SQL-State: S1TAT
X-SQL-Message: RC...: Returning incomplete results, query interrupted by result timeout.  Activity:  1.389M rnd  5.146M seq      0 same seg   55.39K same pg    195 same par      0 disk      0 spec disk      0B /      0 me
```

Empty results thus may be incomplete and it doesn't need to indicate there are no `xsd:integer` literals in DBpedia. A related discussion about the partial results in Virtuoso can be found [here](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/112).

As a solution to your query, you can load the DBpedia from [dumps](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-10) and analyze it locally.

As a side note, your query is syntactically invalid, because it's missing namespace for the `xsd` prefix. You can check the syntax of SPARQL queries via [SPARQLer Query Validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html). You can find the namespaces for common prefixes using [Prefix.cc](http://prefix.cc). Virtuoso that provides the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint ignores the missing namespace for the `xsd` prefix, but it's a good practice to stick to syntactically valid SPARQL queries for greater interoperability.

Comment: I have tested it with and without `xsd` prefix, and so far, on all Virtuoso endpoints, as long as I use the declared prefixes (e.g. http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl for dbpedia) I got no difference in results.

Comment: *This* doesn't appear to be a problem, as discussed in detail by @jindrichm, and as confirmed by [this query, over a smaller number of triples, with your same `FILTER`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX++xsd%3A++<http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23>%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fp+%3Fo+%0D%0AWHERE+{+<http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FBill_Schindler>+%3Fp+%3Fo+%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+(+datatype(%3Fo)+%3D+xsd%3Ainteger+)%0D%0A++++++}%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov: The main problem is in partial results, not in the missing prefix. Thanks for mentioning the default namespace declarations at <http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl>. I wasn't aware of this feature.